# Restore Composer Path

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

A few weeks ago I accidentally deleted a bunch of paths from my environment variables and I just now realized I cannot use the composer command in `cmd.exe`.

I'm pretty sure I used the default settings as they were but I have no idea what path was/what to add to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: How did you install Composer on your system in the first place? Have you tried to install it again? How did it come out?

Comment: "I cannot use the composer command in cmd.exe" - what happens instead? And how is this problem related to Laravel?

Comment: @hakre I got it through the composer setup app. I'm not sure if installing it again would cause some issues with the projects I'm working on right now.

Comment: @Loïc Rutabana: If I understood you right, the composer setup didn't introduce the problems but changing the PATH. When you change the system configuration some applications require that you install them again. The composer setup isn't that invasive, therefore I'd give it a try honestly. It perhaps has even a repair functionality so would be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Open the command line and write

```
WHERE /R C:\ composer
```

you will get the path of composer you have

[image]

so you can add the path (the directory in which the composer executable is located):

```
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
```

to your environment variables and continue using composer

Comment: I found the location but even after adding the path I'm getting the same "'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error

Comment: add the path without the last composer word

Comment: like this 
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

Comment: @LoïcRutabana: I'm pretty sure running the composer setup exe would have done exactly that ;)

Comment: @hakre probably but since I already had composer I was afraid the setup would give me doubles of files and mess something else up.

Comment: @LoïcRutabana: The composer setup.exe is a true setup installer which checks for previous. You may have been a bit too impressed by messing with the PATH ;)